# How to Allow User to Choose to Pay by Invoice OR Credit Card with Drupal Commerce

Tags: commerce

does anyone know if its possible to have a Drupal Commerce checkout form that allows a user to choose whether they want to pay by credit card OR have us send them an invoice so they can pay by check? The form should allow the user to submit the form regardless of which option they choose.

Note: if they choose credit card they would of course have to fill out their credit card information. IF they chose invoice they wouldn't have to pay at this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multiple payment options available, the customer will be prompted to choose the payment option they want.

If you're not picky, you can use [Commerce Custom Offline Payments](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_cop) and just create a payment type for an invoice.

Comment: I didn't realize this existed obviously - well, thank you!